# Is my editor getting confused by python because I have 3.7 and 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Currently on windows 10, using VSCode to run python.
So I recently downloaded python3.8 when I was using python 3.7. Everything was working fine when I was still on python3.7. I now have multiple python directories and I think my imported libraries are throwing errors because of it.

I now have python in(these are results from searching python and right clicking -> open file location) :

```
C:\Python38
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8
C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7
```

As for installed programs I have :

```
python3.8.5(64-bit)
Python launcher
```

Should I add all four paths to my environment...?
Frankly I don't even know anymore how to tackle this problem. I'm not even sure what the problem is I just think its a problem. If someone could link me another stackoverflow or help that would be great.

If this isn't supposed to be a problem then I guess I have some more googling to do...

Thank you

EDIT(commented below): One specific error I keep on getting is when I install keras and tensorflow, and run a program, it keeps on asking me to install tensorflow 2.2.0 even though I've already installed it. I have C:\Python38 and C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38 in my windows path and C:\Python38 as my VSCode path –

Comment: Welcome to Python and multiple environments ..... Each path represents a different environment (at least0. Packages are installed per environment too, so if you install a package in one environment, it won't appear in the others. VS Code allows you to switch environments. What are the *specific errors* you get? Perhaps they are related, perhaps not

Comment: One specific error I keep on getting is when I install keras and tensorflow, and run a program, it keeps on asking me to install tensorflow 2.2.0 even though I've already installed it. I have C:\Python38 and  C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38 in my windows path and C:\Python38 as my VSCode path